# Android: List elements, fixed layout

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, listviewitem

I've got a layout problem. What's odd, I couldn't find a solution online. Maybe someone here would like to help me?
I would like to display a list like that:

[image]

But all I can get is this:

[image]

Here's my xml code for list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@android:id/icon" android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px" android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:textSize="20px" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:textSize="20px" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_weight="0.4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'd appreciate your help, thank you;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` in above code not linearlayout because `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` works only relativelatout not linearlayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView android:id="@android:id/icon" android:layout_width="22px"
        android:layout_height="22px" android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:layout_marginTop="4px"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:textSize="20px" />

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" android:textSize="20px" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It worked, thank you!
I'l accept this answer, if you do what @87element says ;)